# Undefined behavior on deleting char array trought void *

Tags: c++, memory-management, undefined, delete-operator

Is it true that the following yields undefined behavior:

```
void * something = NULL;
char * buffer = new char[10];

something = buffer;
buffer = NULL;

delete [] something; // undefined??
```

Do I first need to cast `something` to `char *` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, strictly when you use `delete[]` the static type of the pointer that you `delete[]` must match the type of the array that you originally allocated or you get undefined behaviour.

Typically, in many implementations, `delete[]` called on a `void*` which is actually an array of a type that has no non-trivial destructor works, but it's not guaranteed.

```
delete[] buffer
```

or

```
delete[] (char*)something
```

would both be valid.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

From the Standard (5.3.5 Delete):

> The value of the operand of delete
>   shall be the pointer value which
>   resulted from a previous array
>   new-expression.72) If not, the
>   behavior is undefined. [Note: this means that the syntax of
>   the delete-expression must match the
>   type of the object allocated by new,
>   not the syntax of the new-expression.
>   ]
>
> In the first alternative (delete
>   object), if the static type of the
>   operand is different from its dynamic
>   type, the static type shall be a base
>   class of the operand’s dynamic type
>   and the static type shall have a
>   virtual destructor or the behavior is
>   undefined. In the second alternative
>   (delete array) if the dynamic type of
>   the object to be deleted differs from
>   its static type, the behavior is
>   undefined*.

**This implies that an object cannot be deleted using a pointer of type void* because there are no objects of type void.

Comment: It's not just the value of the operand it's the type as well, see the next paragraph in 5.3.5 (3).